# How can I execute a userscript on a moz-extension page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, firefox-addon-webextensions, tampermonkey

I want to execute a userscript on a extension's page.

I am using Greasemonkey, is there a permission, setting, or include filter I can use to execute my user script on an extension's page?

Right now I am including my javascript by editing the html file after unpacking and repacking the extension.

However, I would like to be able to change the script without having to edit the extension itself.

Answer (score 4):

Greasemonkey (and Tampermonkey, Violentmonkey, etc.) are `WebExtension`s on Firefox. And, The old "add-on" architecture was disabled with  Firefox 57 ("Quantum").

**WebExtensions are explicitly blocked from operating on (another) extension's pages.** (Imagine the fun chaos if extensions *could* monkey with other extension's pages.)

Refer to [the *Match patterns* Scheme documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#scheme):

- Extensions may operate ***only*** on the `http`, `https`, `ws`, `wss`, `ftp`, `ftps` or `file` schemes.
- The `moz-extension` scheme is not listed.

Note:

1. [mozilla.org pages are also blocked](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310082) for similar reasons.
2. Chrome, Opera, etc., all have similar restrictions.
3. An extension can operate on ***it's own*** `moz-extension://` pages, but that does not apply for Greasemonkey unless you a developing Greasemonkey itself.

Comment: Add-ons was able to modify(another) extension pages?